# backfill data using previous values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, historical-db

I have a table in Snowflake with data that updates at the end of the month as well as data that updates every day (t2). I've joined these tables and now I need to lag the data points that update monthly until the monthly filingDate is equal to AsOfDate.

This is what my table looks like:

| AsOfDate | DailyValue | ID | FilingDate | MonthlyValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/05/23 | 158 | 45 | null | null |
| 7/04/23 | 157 | 45 | null | null |
| 7/03/23 | 157 | 45 | null | null |
| 7/02/23 | 154 | 45 | null | null |
| 7/01/23 | 152 | 45 | null | null |
| 6/30/23 | 152 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 7/05/23 | 34 | 67 | null | null |
| 7/04/23 | 33 | 67 | null | null |
| 7/03/23 | 32 | 67 | null | null |
| 7/02/23 | 28 | 67 | null | null |
| 7/01/23 | 28 | 67 | null | null |
| 6/30/23 | 23 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |

This is what I need my table to look like:

| AsOfDate | DailyValue | ID | FilingDate | MonthlyValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/05/23 | 158 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 7/04/23 | 157 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 7/03/23 | 157 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 7/02/23 | 154 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 7/01/23 | 152 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 6/30/23 | 152 | 45 | 6/30/23 | 4 |
| 7/05/23 | 34 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |
| 7/04/23 | 33 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |
| 7/03/23 | 32 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |
| 7/02/23 | 28 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |
| 7/01/23 | 28 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |
| 6/30/23 | 23 | 67 | 6/30/23 | 82 |
| 6/29/23 | 22 | 67 | 6/27/23 | 80 |
| 6/28/23 | 21 | 67 | 6/27/23 | 80 |
| 6/27/23 | 20 | 67 | 6/27/23 | 80 |
| 6/26/23 | 19 | 67 | 5/31/23 | 77 |

I tried using row_number to find the latest filing date for each id.

`select row_number over (partition by id order by filingDate desc) as rn`

so rn = 1 is the latest filingDate for each date and then I tried using an update statement.

```
update table 
set MonthlyValue = (select b.MonthlyValue
                    from table b
                    where rn = 1 and b.id = a.id and b.MonthlyValue is not null)
from table a
where a.MonthlyValaue is null
```

This did not work in Snowflake. I got an error message of unsupported subquery type. I honestly cannot think of a way of doing this without a subquery, however. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

This type of question comes up so often that I wrote a blog post about it: [Create missing records with Snowflake SQL](https://medium.com/snowflake/create-missing-records-with-snowflake-sql-78d3f00a6f09).

Look at the syntax for using the LAST_VALUE() function.

Comment: I've tried multiple variations of queries in Snowflake using last_value(), and none of them have worked. I still just see nulls where ever filingDate is null.                 
 `SELECT
    AsOfDate,
    DailyValue,
    ID,
    LAST_VALUE(FilingDate IGNORE NULLS) OVER
    (PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY AsOfDate
    ) AS FilingDate,
    LAST_VALUE(MonthlyValue IGNORE NULLS) OVER
    (PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY FilingDate desc
    ) AS MonthlyValue
FROM table`

Comment: Your query works perfectly fine on the sample data you provided. Do you have any other examples where it is not working?

Comment: For me, the query simply returrns the same FilingDate for each AsOfDate. However, I only want backfill wherever FilingDate is less than AsOfDate. I tried using a case when FilingDate < AsOfDate then last_value(MonthlyValue IGNORE NULLS) over (Partition by ID, Order by FilingDate desc) else MonthlyValue in the querry, but that didn't produce what I want either.

Comment: I added a few more rows to my desired output table to illustrate this. I only need last_value(filingDate) and last_value(MonthlyValue) where FilingDate < AsOfDate.

Comment: Try this: 
`SELECT AsOfDate, DailyValue, ID,
  LAST_VALUE(FilingDate IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS FilingDate,     
  LAST_VALUE(MonthlyValue IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MonthlyValue 
FROM table`